# How to insert records to table even if it's duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am holding the URL parts in my table and if the record I will put in already exist in row, I am getting error. For example, I have one row with name `page_name` category, if I want to add new row and have the same `page_name` but different `Page_title` etc. getting error.

I want to continue adding on table. As you see in image below, if `page_name` category added in id

I want to add with same `page_name` in row 8.

[image shows my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8cFt.jpg)

```
    // Calling this function in createPost()
    public function createPageUrlParts(){
        
        $check = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $check->execute();
        
        if($check->rowCount() > 0){
      
            
          
            foreach($check as $val){
                //var_dump($val);
                
                $insertToPageUrl = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `page` (`page_name`,`page_tags`, `page_title`, `page_url`, `page_id`, `date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,now()) ");
                
                $pageUrl = $val['slug']."/".$val['id'];
                
       
                 $insertToPageUrl->execute( [ $val['category'],$val['tags'],$val['slug'],$pageUrl, $val['id'] ] );
                
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I used IGNORE but Not that result I want.
[I tried Ignore here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTvKL.jpg)

Comment: Can you share posts table definition, using `show create table posts`

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` will simply _not_ perform the insert if there is a constraint violation. If you want to insert duplicate values into a column, then you need to remove the `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_tags` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `page_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `page_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

Comment: this is for posts page CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `most_read` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `posted_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

Comment: The error say there is a constraint violation ! are you sure you are selecting the correct Database ?

Comment: I usually adding records to that table. only now i get this error becouse of dublicate entry

Comment: Put the code in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Neither of those tables has any unique columns, it shouldn't prevent you from inserting duplicates. Are you using `ALTER TABLE` to add the unique indexes after creating the tables?

Answer (score 0):

The `page_name` column of the `page` table you are actually using has a UNIQUE index on it. That's what Error 1062 means. Your table is designed so it cannot have more than one row with the same `page_name`. Probably some aspect of your application depends on unique `page_names`.

INSERT IGNORE simply converts the error into a warning, as you saw. You still cannot insert a duplicate.

And, for what it's worth the definition you showed us cannot be the exact SHOW CREATE TABLE definition of the table you actually use.